# Google API post request to IBM blockchain error

Tags: api, post, ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am trying to send reqest from google api script to IBM Blockchain SaaS project Bluemix.
The code is:

```
var url = "https://24f7d912-60f4-4eaf-89c6-b3e34b2247f9_vp1-api.blockchain.ibm.com:443/chaincode";
  var headers =
  {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "method": "query",
   "params": {
       "type": 1,
       "chaincodeID": {
           "name": "c86de893fe7203e09add8c47237ffa377814311d9c3cb21ca4d3d5c4eeca65294d801a1f2e5a2d6b22b91096d9c8e42910046d2ab02d295ad0a0fb0b716e9a69"
       },
       "ctorMsg": {
           "function": "query",
           "args": ["b"]
        },
        "secureContext": "dashboarduser_type0_953add49d4"
    },
    "id": 1
  };
  var options =
     {
      "method" : "post",
      "headers" : headers,
       "MuteHttpExceptions":false
     };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var responseString=response.getContentText();  
}
```

The error message is:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid request","data":"Client must supply a payload for chaincode requests."},"id":null}
```

The request from Firefix Poster was answered correctly.

Comment: Cant see any code that puts a body into the post request. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified **query** as parameter to **method** and **function**  but if you are trying to query using custom function ( Then specify **method** as **query** and **function** as **custom function** name that you have created in chaincode) as:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "query",
   "params": {
       "type": 1,
       "chaincodeID": {
           "name": "chainId"
       },
       "ctorMsg": {
           "function": "customfunctionName",
           "args": ["b"] //Argument to that custom function
        },
        "secureContext": "dashboarduser_type0_953add49d4"
    },
```